# Ogg metadata: cover art tag

Tags: audio, metadata

I'm a software development and newbie in audio engineering topics. I ran Icecast audio stream server and would like to show cover art audio tag to website users. Stream format is Ogg. The problem is - cover tag doesn't display, but I'm sure, that the tag exists in Ogg audio file.

As a result of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548959/is-there-a-way-to-add-album-to-the-stream-title-of-an-icecast2-server) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1479892/unknown-icecast-fails) questions I'm at loss and need to make it clear:

1. Are there "public" and "private" audio metadata? If it's true, how can I identify which is which?
2. What is the Ogg "encapsulated audio"? Shall I convert somehow normal Ogg file to this format to provide cover art tag to an software?

I didn't find answers on these questions in internet.